# initialize a matrix in python of the row number

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to initialize a 3 row, 5 column matrix which contains these values without using a for loop?

```
[[0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2 2 2]]
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Since you are asking these values specifically, the answer should actually be `matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]`

Comment: You might get better answers if you explain where the artificial "without using a for loop" restriction comes from.

Comment: I've got very large datasets and I am looking for ways to speed up the code.  I was hoping to initialize a matrix and then do operations on the entire matrix instead of having to loop through every sample, thinking that this might speed up the code.

Comment: Can you use NumPy?  That would be the obvious way to go if you're looking for speedups for large datasets.

Comment: Yes, I have NumPy.  How could I implement NumPy to speed up the analysis?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.

```
i = 0
matrix = []
while i <=2:
    matrix += [[i]*5]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any `for` loops or list comprehensions, you can use a combination of built-in functions:

```
map(list, zip(*[range(3)] * 5))
```

Comment: I like this as it is very succinct. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with large datasets and are worried about performance, you might want to consider putting your data into a two-dimensional [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) array. Here are a couple of ways of generating the matrix you ask for in NumPy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.indices((3, 5))[0]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> np.repeat(np.arange(3), 5).reshape((3, 5))
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

The first of these is simpler, but a little bit wasteful: the [`np.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) call actually generates the array you want (which could be regarded as an array of row indices) along with a companion array of column indices:

```
>>> np.indices((3, 5))[1]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

with both arrays packed conveniently into a single array of shape `(2, 3, 5)`.  If you need that second array anyway for what you're doing then `np.indices` is the way to go (though in that case you may also want to look into NumPy's `mgrid`, `ogrid` and `meshgrid` functions).  The second solution with [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) only generates the values you need, and not surprisingly, finishes about twice as fast on my machine when I bump the size of the matrix up to `(3000, 5000)`:

```
In [19]: %timeit np.indices((3000, 5000))[0]
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.repeat(np.arange(3000), 5000).reshape((3000, 5000))
10 loops, best of 3: 88.4 ms per loop
```

Having said that, using `np.repeat` in this way is a little bit of an antipattern in NumPy: it's often better to avoid the repetition by creating a 2d array with 3 rows and a *single* column, and rely on NumPy's [**broadcasting**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to interpret this correctly when it's combined with other arrays.  If you go that way, all you need is:

```
>>> np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

This is an array of shape `(3, 1)`; a subsequent operation with an array of shape `(5,)` or `(1, 5)` (for example) would be subject to NumPy's broadcasting rules, producing an output of shape `(3, 5)`.  For example, here's what happens when we add a 1d array of zeros to the above:

```
>>> np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis] + np.zeros(5, dtype=int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

And for completeness, here's one more variation, using [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
>>> np.tile(np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis], (1, 5))
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

All of these solutions should have reasonably similar performance for large values of `3` and `5`; if this is a bottleneck, you'll want to do timings on your machine to decide which to use.  On my machine, the `+np.zeros` broadcasting solution beats the others by some margin.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of easy way to understand for Python Beginner.

```
matrix = []
for data in range(3):
    matrix.append([data] * 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using:

```
[[data] * 5 for data in range(3)]
```